# Problem related to the compliance voltage

Tags: characteristic-impedance

I have a question that I am using a stimulator to generate biphasic current source for stimulation. At the output of the stimulator, a 1K resistor is in series with 0.1uF capacitor. The I use two scope probes to measure current and voltage respectively from the oscilloscope. One probe is across the resistor. Another one is across the resistor and capacitor. The power supply of stimulator is 12V. If I lower the external  power less than 12V, it will reach the compliance voltage limit. Then the voltage wave across resistor and capacitor become flat( compliance limit, constant charging). But the current is linearly decreasing which means the impedance is increasing.

V+ is connected to the adjustable external power supply. Link 2 is the result observed from the oscilloscope and the shady parts are missing when voltage reached the compliance limit.

Why would the current waveform be linearly decreasing(a resistor is in series with a capacitor)?

[image]

Waveform observed from oscilloscope:

[image]

USB circuitry:

[image]

Biphasic current source:

[image]

Comment: A link to a circuit would help. Are your scope probe inputs floating - most scope probes have a common earth point on the scope and therefore you'll be shorting out one of your components when you connect them if you are not careful.

Comment: Be sure to include the load in the circuit diagram.  I understand the current measurement through a 1K current sense (though 1K is pretty high), but I don't understand your method of voltage measurement.

Comment: It is not possible to give a definitive answer without a schematic, however I will make a suggestion. It *sounds* like you have a current source feeding a series resistor and capacitor to ground. If you have reached the compliance limit of the current source, it will presumably be acting more like a voltage source in which case the voltage across the capacitor will be increasing (charging) and the voltage across the resistor will be decreasing, so the current will also be decreasing. The point of the compliance limit is that the current is no longer constant.

Comment: Just a circuit diagram and not the board layout drawings are needed. Have you tried making the capacitor a bit bigger to see if the current source does not go wrong when the compliance limit is reached? I suspect that the voltage on the cap is rising and reaching a point where the current source refuses to work correctly.